# How to include video with subtitle .mkv file in beamer

Tags: beamer, video

I would like to add video format .mkv in frame

i tired the following code but with no luck is there any solution 
I need to add this particular extension of video (.mkv) because it conains video and subtitles

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{multimedia}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\movie[width=8cm,height=4.5cm]{test}{m.mkv}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Workaround:**

Convert the video (including the subtitles) into a format which can be embeded into beamer.

For example

```
ffmpeg -i m.mkv -vf subtitles=m.mkv m.mp4
```

will embed the subtitles in a `.mp4` file which might work with `media9`.